# How to fill any circle drawn on a map with smaller circles having variable radius?

Tags: php, math, geolocation

**To Do**

Get sub areas of a bigger area in order to use it in subsequent calls to an API that provides data by location, but has Radius Limit.

**Approach**

- Wrap the big area in a square
- Use a method to get a new location given a main location, an angle and a distance
- Calculate the first top-left sub-location position
- Get the rest of sub-locations from top-left to bottom-right, except ones that get outside of main area too much

  [image]

**Issue**

When the radius of the main area increases and approaches the poles, calculating a location based on another location, angle and distance, gets tricky. **Please note how the top of the main area is not covered by sub areas.**
    [image]
    And it gets to something like below when radius of main area increases dramatically.
[image]

Given the fact that my function that calculates location base on other location, angle and distance is the following (PHP). How can I improve it order to make it work regardless of what the bit area is?

```
function getLocation($lat, $lng, $dist, $brng)
{
    $lat1 = degToRad($lat);
    $lon1 = degToRad($lng);
    $dist = $dist/AVG_ERAD; //Earth's radius in km
    $brng = degToRad($brng);

    $lat2 = asin(sin($lat1) * cos($dist) +
        cos($lat1) * sin($dist) * cos($brng));

    $lon2 = $lon1 + atan2(sin($brng) * sin($dist) * cos($lat1),
            cos($dist) - sin($lat1) * sin($lat2));
    $lon2 = fmod(($lon2 + 3 * pi()),(2 * pi())) - pi();

    return array(
        'lat' => radToDeg($lat2),
        'lng' => radToDeg($lon2)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest another order of small circle's filling:

1. Get the northest point of big circle (step R from center C to the
   north), make it a center of the first small circle
2. Step about r*3/2 to the east and west until distance to C exceeds R+r to make the first row
3. Step central small circle about r*3/2 to the south. Repeat (2)
4. Repeat (3) until center small circle leaves big circle

Example of traversal order:

```
    5   4   1   2   3
12  11  10  6   7   8  9
        ... 13...
```

Comment: I think this is quite a good approach. I shall try it and let you know how it works. Thanks!

Comment: Your suggested approach makes all sense and fixes the issue. Thank you!